# Remapping Ctrl-Alt-Arrow in Windows 10 using AutoHotkey

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am trying to remap Ctrl-Alt-Right and Ctrl-Alt-Left to imitate Ctrl-Win-Right and Ctrl-Win-Left, respectively. I followed the instructions given in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/948616/windows-10-change-shortcut-keys-to-switch-between-desktops), and succeeded in mapping Ctrl-Arrow to give the correct result, but when I change the script to

```
#NoTrayIcon
!^Right::^#Right
!^Left::^#Left
```

and run it, my desired functionality is not achieved. Why is this? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
!^Right:: send {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}
```

or

```
!^Right:: sendevent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right down}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}{Left up}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! Do you have any idea why the other way did not work?

Comment: "!^Right" isn't a key you can replace by another one. It's a combination of three keys.