# Multiple Virtual Desktops on Windows 7 with the same keybord shortcuts as in Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I enable multiple virtual desktops on Windows 7 and allows to configure the same shortcuts for cycling between desktops as the standard Windows 10 shortcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>WIN</kbd> + Left/Right Arrow)?

Comment: When you say multiple desktop, do you mean similar to how Android on mobile works (where it has multiple screens and you're calling each screen a different desktop)?

Comment: I mean multiple virtual desktops (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop) - not sure how that works on Android.

Comment: The link you shows that for Windows, there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtuaWin (not sure if meets your needs but your question is off topic here, sorry :( )

Comment: Thanks, VirtuaWin did the trick! But why is this question off-topic? There are tons of question asking for shortcuts for Virtual Desktops (e.g. http://superuser.com/questions/948616/windows-10-change-shortcut-keys-to-switch-between-desktops?rq=1).

Comment: Asking about Virtual Desktops are fine but software recommendations are not (hence why I assume you got a downvote). Your first line is `is there a program that enables multiple virtual...`

Comment: I have edited your quesiton, it should be on topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this on Windows 7 alone.

You can use VirtuaWin for your needs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtuaWin