# Windows 10: Removing Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a way to enable lets say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> or something like that, which I found: [Windows 10: Change shortcut keys to switch between desktops](https://superuser.com/questions/948616/windows-10-change-shortcut-keys-to-switch-between-desktops). All that code was really good, and worked, but how can I remove/disable/intercept the keys for the default shortcuts. I would also want to know about Windows+Tab, and if I can disable/change that.